# Localstorage change event + react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React. I have a function that listen to localstorage event change like `window.addEventListener("storage", () => {....}`. If I change value of a key that I listen in storage manually by my hand, this code work. But if I use `setItem` to change value. It doesn't work anytime. Help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because The `StorageEvent` doesn't work on the same page that is making the changes.
For more info check here [Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent)

Comment: Thank so much. But if I wanna listen storage changes in my React app, do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @DucAnhPham I don't see where is the problem . in the same tab just run the function that you passed in the listener after `setItem` in a different tab the listener will do the job

Comment: My app is a single web page app. So I dont have a different tab. I am only using in one tab.